# Ruby - Array of Hashes to CSV

Tags: arrays, ruby, csv, hash

I have collected some data and saved it to an array of hashes in the form of:

```
info = [
  {'Name' => 'Alex', 'Tel' => 999, 'E-mail' => "bla@bla.com"},
  {'Name' => 'Ali', 'Tel' => 995, 'E-mail' => "ali@bla.com"}
  # ...
]
```

But not all information is always there:

```
{'Name' => 'GuyWithNoTelephone', 'E-mail' => "poor@bla.com"}
```

I want to turn this information into a CSV file. Here is what I tried:

```
def to_csv (info)
  CSV.open("sm-data.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ["Name", "Tel", "E-mail"]
    info.each do |person|
      csv << person.values
```

When I try this, the format of the table is not correct, and say, if a telephone number is missing, then the e-mail of that person appears at telephone column.

How can I selectively write this info to the CSV file, i.e how can I tell to skip columns if a value is missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> But sadly when I try this, the format of the table is not correct, and say, if a telephone number is missing, then the e-mail of that person appears at telephone column.

That's because you are omitting the telephone number in that case, providing just 2 of the 3 values. To fix this, you simply have to provide all 3 values, even if they don't exist in the hash:

```
csv << ['Name', 'Tel', 'E-mail']
info.each do |person|
  csv << [person['Name'], person['Tel'], person['E-Mail']]
end
```

or via [`Hash#values_at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Hash.html#method-i-values_at):

```
csv << ['Name', 'Tel', 'E-mail']
info.each do |person|
  csv << person.values_at('Name', 'Tel', 'E-Mail')
end
```

For:

```
{'Name' => 'GuyWithNoTelephone', 'E-mail' => "poor@bla.com"}
```

this results in:

```
csv << ['GuyWithNoTelephone', nil, 'poor@bla.com']
```

which generates this output: (note the two commas, denoting an empty field in-between)

```
"GuyWithNoTelephone,,poor@bla.com\n"
```

Comment: Thanks, very simple straightforward and fast answer!

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
  def to_csv(csv_filename="sm-data.csv")
    # Get all unique keys into an array:
    keys = info.map(&:keys).inject(&:|)
    CSV.open(csv_filename, "wb") do |csv|
      csv << keys
      info.each do |hash|
        # fetch values at keys location, inserting null if not found.
        csv << hash.values_at(*keys)
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: @mudasobwa throwing all keys into a huge array and calling `uniq` should return the union of all keys.

Comment: I think `info.map(&:keys).inject(&:|)` is an elegant way ... for a more civilized age ;-)

Comment: Edited the answer @Stefan

Comment: The original code was `info.flat_map(&:keys).uniq` (which IMO reads easier than `info.map(&:keys).inject(&:|)`). @AlekseiMatiushkin, how was `flat_map` redundant? And what was wrong with `uniq`?

Answer (score 0):

Simple as this:

```
path = "data/backtest-results.csv"
CSV.open(path, "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ["Asset", "Strategy", "Profit"]
  result_array.each do |p|
    csv << p.map { |key, value| value }
  end
end
```

use  "(File.file?(path) ? "ab" : "wb")" rather than "wb" if you want to continue adding as the new data comes